# ¿Cómo enviar Foto o imagen Android a servidor php?

Tags: android

Hasta ahora solo tengo este código que consiste en tomar una foto o cargar una imagen pero deseo alojar esta imagen en la carpeta upload de mi servidor en banahosting y a su ves guardar la ruta de la imagen en una base de datos mysql

```
public class FotografiaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etUsuario, etNservicio;
    private static String APP_DIRECTORY = "MyPictureApp/";
    private static String MEDIA_DIRECTORY = APP_DIRECTORY + "PictureApp";

    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS = 100;
    private final int PHOTO_CODE = 200;
    private final int SELECT_PICTURE = 300;

    private ImageView mSetImage;
    private Button mOptionButton;
    private RelativeLayout mRlView;

    private String mPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fotografia);
        etUsuario=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsuario);
        etNservicio=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNservicio);
        mSetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_picture);
        mOptionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_options_button);
        mRlView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_view);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String dato= extras.getString("Usuarios").toString();
        etUsuario.setText(dato);
        String datos= extras.getString("Nservicio").toString();
        etNservicio.setText(datos);
        if(mayRequestStoragePermission())
            mOptionButton.setEnabled(true);
        else
            mOptionButton.setEnabled(false);


        mOptionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showOptions();
            }
        });

    }
    public void checkCancelar(View arg0){
        Intent intent = new Intent(FotografiaActivity.this,DashboardActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("Usuarios",etUsuario.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
        FotografiaActivity.this.finish();
    }
    public void checkFinalizar(View arg0){
        Intent intent = new Intent(FotografiaActivity.this,UbicacionActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("Usuarios",etUsuario.getText().toString());
        extras.putString("Nservicio", etNservicio.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
        FotografiaActivity.this.finish();
    }
    private boolean mayRequestStoragePermission() {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            return true;

        if((checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                (checkSelfPermission(CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            return true;

        if((shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) || (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA))){
            Snackbar.make(mRlView, "Los permisos son necesarios para poder usar la aplicación",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS);
                }
            });
        }else{
            requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void showOptions() {
        final CharSequence[] option = {"Tomar foto", "Elegir de galeria", "Cancelar"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FotografiaActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Eleige una opción");
        builder.setItems(option, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(option[which] == "Tomar foto"){
                    openCamera();
                }else if(option[which] == "Elegir de galeria"){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona app de imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.exists();

        if(!isDirectoryCreated)
            isDirectoryCreated = file.mkdirs();

        if(isDirectoryCreated){
            Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            String imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";

            mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
                    + File.separator + imageName;

            File newFile = new File(mPath);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
            startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("file_path", mPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        mPath = savedInstanceState.getString("file_path");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch (requestCode){
                case PHOTO_CODE:
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                            new String[]{mPath}, null,
                            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> Uri = " + uri);
                                }
                            });


                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                    mSetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    break;
                case SELECT_PICTURE:
                    Uri path = data.getData();
                    mSetImage.setImageURI(path);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS){
            if(grantResults.length == 2 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(FotografiaActivity.this, "Permisos aceptados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mOptionButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }else{
            showExplanation();
        }
    }

    private void showExplanation() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FotografiaActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Permisos denegados");
        builder.setMessage("Para usar las funciones de la app necesitas aceptar los permisos");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de pasar una imagen a un servicio web es pasarla en formato Base64.

En android a partir de la versión 2.2 tienes la librería Base64: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Primero tienes que convertir la imagen en un array de bytes

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm = Bitmap
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

Luego convertirla a Base64

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Una vez hecho esto ya tienes que montar la llamada al servicio web y pasar el base64 como un parámetro de la llamada al servicio web.

En el PHP del servidor recoges el $_POST correspondiente, decodificas el Base64 y guardas el fichero

```
file_put_contents('img.png', base64_decode($_POST['imagen_base64']));
```

Comment: Una apreciación, si lo envías en base64 debes enviar otro campo que indique el nombre del archivo, ya que la creación del base64 solo genera la cadena de texto del archivo.  O puedes añadirle delante del base64 el nombre del archivo, con un separador tipo ';', para que PHP los separe y te cree luego el nombre correcto.

Comment: Correcto, pero es algo obvio. Cualquier sistema de encapsulado/cifrado es solo para el contenido del fichero.